# Can power of a prime number be approximated by product of powers of two adjacent prime numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

With prime numbers $a < b < c$ and no primes exist in ranges $(a, b)$ and $(b, c)$, is it possible that there exists positive integers $x$, $y$, $z$ such that $|a^x c^z-b^y|=2$?

Comment: Do you intend to rule out the case a=2? Gerhard "Two Is Also A Prime" Paseman, 2020.01.31.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman If $a=2$, $|a^x c^z - b^y|$ is odd, so ...

Comment: So the one case where you can prove there are such terms close to each other is ruled out.  Gerhard "Distance One Seems Not Wanted" Paseman, 2020.01.31.

Comment: Write a as b-alpha, c as b+beta, and delta as alpha times beta. Modulo delta, the sum is b^y(b^{x+z-y)-1)  + (z*beta - x*alpha)b^{y-1}. Since alpha and beta are both even, there are lots of times when this implies the difference is divisible by four.  Gerhard "Not Seeing Many Solutions Here" Paseman, 2020.01.31.